# Android What should I use States or location?

Tags: android, location

Im newbiew to Android developmt. I'm currently developing an app and I want either the user to be able to set up their state(meaning CA, IA WA etc) only the first time using it, or should I let the app use the location? What would be the easy/ best way to go and why? Do you guys have any examples?
 Thanks and if you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a balance you must strike between having your app be psychic and having it be non-intrusive. One thing to bear in mind is you do not need a permission to ask the user their location of preference, you DO however need to ask for permissions to discover their location using sensors.

Also, if you use sensors you may need to check each time. I do not know what your app is for but if someone is using their phone on vacation (a common thing) you may get a state that they do not actually want to be stored as "their" state.

I would say that if its simply a preference, there is no reason to cause the user to worry, and give them an opportunity to set it how the choose.

If it's something that should be updated periodically, THEN you would want to use location sensors.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be actual travel.  When I sit down in my cubicle the sensors in my phone decide that I am in an Eastern European city, rather than Hillsboro, Oregon.  I've been locked out of a few different sites because the GPS tells them that I am logging in from a country I am not normally in.

Comment: Right, there is all those fun problems as well, also: Hello fellow Oregonian!